# Kubernetes Volumes access modes

Tags: kubernetes

I was going through in depth of K8s volumes and one of the concept messed me up. It would be great if someone could explain me this.
These are the modes in K8s volumes.

ReadWriteOnce -- the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node

ReadOnlyMany -- the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes

ReadWriteMany -- the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes

1. What if I run two mysql pods on same node and the mode is ReadWriteOnce ? How my both pods will write?
2. What if I run two mysql pods on two different nodes and the mode is ReadWriteOnce ? How my both pods will write?
3. What if I run two mysql pods on same node and the mode is ReadWriteMany ? How my both pods will write?
4. What if I run two mysql pods on two different nodes and the mode is ReadWriteMany ? How my both pods will write?

All have same pod replica.

Answer (score 2):

> What if I run two mysql pods on same node and the node is ReadWriteOnce ? How my both pods will write?

If you run two DBMS systems (e.g. MySQL or PostgreSQL) in Pods, they are both independent and they should have **two independent PersistentVolumeClaims**. Only run single-node DBMS for test purposes. For production consider a *distributed database* that replicates the data.

> What if I run two mysql pods on two different node and the node is ReadWriteOnce ? How my both pods will write?

As I recommended above, the two should be independent (unless you use a distributed database like [cockroachDB](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/product/kubernetes/)) so running on different nodes is perfectly fine.

> What if I run two mysql pods on same different node and the node is ReadWriteMany ? How my both pods will write?

MySQL is a single-node DBMS system, it should not share volumes/files with other instances unless you run a clustered system.

> What if I run two mysql pods on two different node and the node is ReadWriteMany ? How my both pods will write?

Same as above, single-node system should not share volumes/files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jonas,  what if I run two pods of MySql on same node?

Comment: @Aditya if you want a distributed database, maybe https://github.com/pingcap/tidb might be something for you?

Comment: No, its same mysql pod with two replica?

Comment: @Aditya how do you run your MySQL in a distributed mode? Isn't that two independent databases with different? Are they replicated to eachother?

Comment: I've like no idea. Right now I'm using RDS AWS from K8s cluster using external name service. I'm just trying to understand if we deploy HA Mysql pod using Deployment what should be my approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233693/discussion-between-aditya-and-jonas).

Comment: @Aditya Let me know what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I've asked for same database either mysql or postgresql. You are correct. I just wanted to know for same database type with same deployment

Comment: Always deploy database with `StatefulSet` not `Deployment`.

Answer (score -1):

Just explored and implemented and got few information and thanks to @jonas

What if I run two mysql pods on same node and the mode is ReadWriteOnce ? How my both pods will write?

- We cannot schedule two pods of mysql on same node, it will result in crashloopbackoff.

What if I run two mysql pods on two different nodes and the mode is ReadWriteOnce ? How my both pods will write?

- Since the mode is ReadWriteOnce, the data will be written by only one pod in one node based on order.

What if I run two mysql pods on same node and the mode is ReadWriteMany ? How my both pods will write?

- Was not able to schedule two pods on single node. Resulted in crashloopbackoff

What if I run two mysql pods on two different nodes and the mode is ReadWriteMany ? How my both pods will write?

- Need to use EFS CSI Driver in case of AWS or Shared volume like network attached storage. Check out this link [Kubernetes PVC with ReadWriteMany on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212904/kubernetes-pvc-with-readwritemany-on-aws)

Comment: You can perfectly fine run MySql in two pods on the same node. But not using the same Deployment.

Comment: Correct! what my query was using the same replica, it cannot be done.

Comment: Yes, so what is written in your answer is incorrect.

Comment: I've just updated my question to "All have same pod replica." now my answer make sense? I guess I missed this part while asking