# Kubernetes PVC with RWM on AWS EKS

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, amazon-ebs, aws-ebs-csi-driver

I want to setup an Opensearch cluster on AWS EKS. The data nodes uses PVC currently with `ReadWriteOnce` accessMode. However, the problem is whenever I am trying to add another node with the same mount the pod fails to come up with the below error:

```
Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[opensearch-data1], unattached volumes=[opensearch-data1]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

This is expected with `RWO` as I understand.

I am using EBS as my underlying storage. If I try to use `ReadWriteMany` the pod goes in pending state forever. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212904/kubernetes-pvc-with-readwritemany-on-aws) post EBS doesn't support `RWM` however I am not keen on using EFS because of performance/cost concerns. Is there any other way out that will help me scale up multiple pods using the same mount volume.

Comment: What is the reason for trying to get nodes to share a data volume? I suspect this won't work even if the k8s issues were eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it as a StatefulSet? You should not expect one volume connected to many containers instead it must be multiple volumes mapped to the multiple pods.